# Android draw image with width 1029 * height 1029 pixel

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview, android-image, android-bitmap

In my Android application, I need an image with size of width 1029 * height 1029 pixel (image center crop is allowed) . The original image width and height is above than 1029 pixels.

I have tried the following things.
I have placed the image in a image view and capture the bitmap I got the following exception.

```
Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2322x4128, max=4096x4096)
```

This is the layout design of image view.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_try1"
    android:layout_width="425dp"
    android:layout_height="425dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:contentDescription="@string/icd" />
```

( I am not sure 425dp gives 1029 pixels, just a try).

I used the following code to capture the bitmap from image view.

```
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    // resultant bitmap is save into save in SDcard.
```

How can I get an image with width 1029 * height 1029 pixel resolution as bitmap? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

as the exceptions states your bitmap is too large. The height exceed the maximum value. What you can do is to downscale the bitmap. The first step would be to load only the meta-info of your bitmap with

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decode*(..., o);
```

setting `inJustDecodeBounds = true`, will make the `decode*` method return a null Bitmap, but the  `BitmapFactory.Options` will contain the width/height of the bitmap in pixels. Knowing those two, you can calculate the value of `inSampleSize` that you need to scale the bitmap to with/height close to your constraint (1029 px). From the documentation of `inSampleSize`

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original
>   image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is
>   the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single
>   pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an
>   image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the
>   number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the
>   decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will
>   be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.